# Pyrostreams Filter Table with Form

Tags: php, plugins, stream, pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

I am displaying data in a table using `{{streams}}` and page types and would like to filter and sort the data.

There are no tags to automatically generate filters. However, I can auto generate a {{ form }} for inserting a stream record and - an **input form** is exactly the UI we need for a **filter form**.

How could I override the default **input** action of the form plugin to perform a **filtering** of my table data (stream)?

What is a good method of sorting the data? I see a PyroFilter plugin exists but not much documentation and no examples in the Pyro core as the plugin author suggests.

I love PyroCMS because of streams (and the amazingly compact and modular code), and gaining the ability to easily filter and sort would be remarkable. This just feels like exactly the sort of thing pyrostreams was built for because the UI components are already there.

Any help with this would be appreciated.